# Running Ubuntu 14.04 Can't install updates from Software updater

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

I'm a new Ubuntu user, and I have a fair amount of knowledge about how things are supposed to work, but I'm having a serious issue with my software updater. I don't know what else to do. I've tried running commands from the Terminal, to no avail.

I have run commands through the terminal and the resulted output is as follows:

```
"dpkg: error: reading package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available': Input/output error"
```

I can't install or update anything.

Comment: What commands have you tried running from the terminal? Did it return any error messages?

Comment: Please refine your question- are there any errors? Have you attempted to run updates via the software centre first? Failing that, sudo apt-get update -f and possibly sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y

Comment: I've tried a few different commands from the terminal such as sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade -y.  I always get an error code when it gets to /var/lib/dpkg/available.  I get an error code (2).  The whole code is as follows E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpfg error code (2).  I'm gonna try these commands one more time.

Comment: I just entered sudo apt-get update -y, and got the following message: "dpkg: error: reading package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available': Input/output error"

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Where is the edit button?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Parto.  I appreciate it.  I hope someone can see this and help me.  I'm lost.